# how to write a cron expression which run at 12 pm and run for every two hours till 12 am and runs everyday for same?

Tags: cronexpression

JobDetail Management = new JobDetail("Management", "NJobGroup", ClinicSubscription.class);

CronTrigger cr = new CronTrigger("ccr", "NJobGroup", "0 0 00 * * ?");
 sche.scheduleJob(clinicManagement, cr);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Midnight (`0`) or every two hours (`/2`) in the range midday to ten pm, inclusively (`12-22`):

```
0 0,12-22/2 * * * command.sh
```